# find frequency of each unique column in a matrix or data frame

Tags: r

I want to find frequency of a matrix by their column. for example for matrix x below

```
   x <- matrix(c(rep(1:4,3),rep(2:5,2)),4,5)
   x
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
   [1,]    1    1    1    2    2
   [2,]    2    2    2    3    3
   [3,]    3    3    3    4    4
   [4,]    4    4    4    5    5
```

now how can find frequency of each unique column and create a matrix that each column is a unique column of x and the last row is added as the frequency of it in matrix x

```
 #freqmatrix
        [,1] [,2]
 [,1]      1  2
 [,2]      2  3
 [,3]      3  4
 [,4]      4  5
 [,5]      3  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your end goal, exactly? In other words, how are you going to work with this data further? If it's just tabulation, doesn't `paste()` get you to the answer?

```
x <- matrix(c(rep(1:4,3),rep(2:5,2)),4,5)
x1 <- data.frame(table(apply(x, 2, paste, collapse = ", ")))
#         Var1 Freq
# 1 1, 2, 3, 4    3
# 2 2, 3, 4, 5    2
```

If you do want `Var1` separated, you can use `read.csv()` on that column.

```
cbind(read.csv(text = as.character(x1$Var1), header = FALSE), x1[-1])
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 Freq
# 1  1  2  3  4    3
# 2  2  3  4  5    2
```

Or, if you prefer to transpose your output:

```
t(cbind(read.csv(text = as.character(x1$Var1), header = FALSE), x1[-1]))
#      [,1] [,2]
# V1      1    2
# V2      2    3
# V3      3    4
# V4      4    5
# Freq    3    2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution avoiding converting the matrix to a list of lists, but it is also a little messy:

```
x.unique <- unique(x, MARGIN  = 2)

freq <- apply(x.unique, MARGIN = 2, 
              function(b) sum(apply(x, MARGIN = 2, function(a) all(a == b)))
        )

rbind(x.unique, freq)

     [,1] [,2]
        1    2
        2    3
        3    4
        4    5
freq    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be a little messy as it involves lists of lists which I couldn't avoid:

```
x <- matrix(c(rep(1:4,3),rep(2:5,2)),4,5)
#convert columns to elements in list
y <- apply(x, 2, list)

#Get unique columns
unique_y <- unique(unlist(y, recursive=FALSE))

#Get column frequencies
frequencies <- sapply(unique(y), function(f) sum(unlist(y, recursive=FALSE) %in% f))

#Bind unique columns with frequencies
rbind(simplify2array(unique_y), frequencies)
```

And behold:

```
            [,1] [,2]
               1    2
               2    3
               3    4
               4    5
frequencies    3    2
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner using `aggregate` (if your input is a `data.frame`):

```
y <- matrix(c(1:4, 2:5, 1:4, 1,3,4,5, 2:5), ncol=5)
> y
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    3    2    3    3
# [3,]    3    4    3    4    4
# [4,]    4    5    4    5    5

z <- as.data.frame(t(y))
> t(aggregate(z, by=z, length)[1:(ncol(z)+1)])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# V1      1    1    2
# V2      2    3    3
# V3      3    4    4
# V4      4    5    5
# V1.1    2    1    2
```

**Note:** this solution will be fast if the number of columns in your input matrix `x` is greater than its nrows, i.e., `ncol(x) >> nrow(x)`.

Comment: thanks, as my dataframs is large, your notification was good.