# unexpected output from aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate

While experimenting with `aggregate` for another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434632/find-frequency-of-each-unique-column-in-a-matrix-or-data-frame/14436500#14436500), I encountered a rather strange result. I'm unable to figure out why and am wondering if what I'm doing is totally wrong.

Suppose, I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
                     V2 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
                     V3 = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L), 
                     V4 = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L)), 
                  .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), 
        row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
> df
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  2  3  4
# 2  2  3  4  5
# 3  1  2  3  4
# 4  2  3  4  5
# 5  3  4  5  6
# 6  1  2  3  4
```

Now, if I want to output a `data.frame` with *unique rows* with an additional column indicating their frequency in `df`. For this example,

```
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 x
# 1  1  2  3  4 3
# 2  2  3  4  5 2
# 3  3  4  5  6 1
```

I obtained this output using `aggregate` by experimenting as follows:

```
> aggregate(do.call(paste, df), by=df, print)

# [1] "1 2 3 4" "1 2 3 4" "1 2 3 4"
# [1] "2 3 4 5" "2 3 4 5"
# [1] "3 4 5 6"
#   V1 V2 V3 V4                         x
# 1  1  2  3  4 1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 4
# 2  2  3  4  5          2 3 4 5, 2 3 4 5
# 3  3  4  5  6                   3 4 5 6
```

So, this gave me the pasted string. So, if I were to use `length` instead of `print`, it should give me the number of such occurrences, which is the desired result, which was the case (as shown below).

```
> aggregate(do.call(paste, df), by=df, length)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 x
# 1  1  2  3  4 3
# 2  2  3  4  5 2
# 3  3  4  5  6 1
```

And this seemed to work. However, when the `data.frame` dimensions are 4*2500, the output `data.frame` is 1*2501 instead of 4*2501 (all rows are unique, so the frequency is 1).

```
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:3, 1e4, replace = TRUE), nrow=4))
> o <- aggregate(do.call(paste, df), by=df, length)
> dim(o)
# [1]    1 2501
```

I tested with smaller data.frames with just unique rows and it gives the right output (change `nrow=40`, for example). However, when the dimensions of the matrix increase, this doesn't seem to work. And I just can't figure out what's going wrong! Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe, because strings get too long and `as.character` inserts linebreaks?

Comment: yes, as an alternative you could do `aggregate(rep(1, nrow(df)), df, FUN = length)`.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `as.character()` as each of it's arguments is a length 1 vector. To see that this part works, just do `do.call(paste, df[1:3, ])`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is how `aggregate.data.frame()` determines the groups.

In `aggregate.data.frame()` there is a loop which forms the grouping variable `grp`. In that loop, `grp` is altered/updated via:

```
grp <- grp * nlevels(ind) + (as.integer(ind) - 1L)
```

The problem with your example if that once `by` is converted to factors, and the loop has gone over *all* of these factors, in your example `grp` ends up being:

```
Browse[2]> grp
[1] Inf Inf Inf Inf
```

Essentially the looping update pushed the values of `grp` to a number indistinguishable from `Inf`.

Having done that, `aggregate.data.frame()` later does this

```
y <- y[match(sort(unique(grp)), grp, 0L), , drop = FALSE]
```

and this is where the earlier problem now manifests itself as

```
dim(y[match(sort(unique(grp)), grp, 0L), , drop = FALSE])
```

because

```
match(sort(unique(grp)), grp, 0L)
```

clearly returns just `1`:

```
> match(sort(unique(grp)), grp, 0L)
[1] 1
```

as there is only one unique value of `grp`.

Comment: There are just too many groups formed by `by`. I don't recommend you do this but another way to see the issue is to form the sub-data frames that aggregate would work on it the `grp` didn't go to `Inf`: `length(split(do.call(paste, df), df))`. **WARNING** that will some consume all your RAM (on my 4GB laptop I was quickly thrashing swap space).

Comment: @Arun yep, `debugonce()` is your friend for this sort of thing.