# Why is subsetting on a "logical" type slower than subsetting on "numeric" type?

Tags: r, subset

Suppose we've a `vector` (or a `data.frame` for that matter) as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(10, 1e6, TRUE)
```

And one wants to get all values of `x` where `x > 4`, say:

```
a1 <- x[x > 4] # (or) 
a2 <- x[which(x > 4)]

identical(a1, a2) # TRUE
```

I think most people would prefer `x[x > 4]`. But surprisingly (at least to me), subsetting using `which` is faster!

```
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(x[x > 4], x[which(x > 4)], times = 100)

Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
        x[x > 4] 56.59467 57.70877 58.54111 59.94623 104.51472   100
 x[which(x > 4)] 26.62217 27.64490 28.31413 29.97908  99.68973   100
```

It's about 2.1 times faster on mine.

One possibility for the difference, I thought, could be due to the fact that `which` doesn't consider `NA` but `>` returns them as well. But then logical operation itself should be the reason for this difference, which is *not* the case (obviously). That is:

```
microbenchmark(x > 4, which(x > 4), times = 100)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
        x > 4  8.182576 10.06163 12.68847 14.64203 60.83536   100
 which(x > 4) 18.579746 19.94923 21.43004 23.75860 64.20152   100
```

Using `which` is about 1.7 times slower just before subsetting. But `which` seems to catch up drastically on/during subsetting.

It seems not possible to use my usual weapon of choice `debugonce` ([thanks to @GavinSimpson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439987/unexpected-output-from-aggregate#comment20106852_14440620)) as `which` calls `.Internal(which(x))` whereas `==` calls `.Primitive("==")`.

My question therefore is why is `[` on `numeric` type resulting from `which`  faster than logical vector resulting from `>`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think I should move out of the comments and add an answer. This is my hunch building up on what the others have answered and discussed. (I'm sure the real answer exists in the C source for subset_dflt.)

Once I have a vector `x` and a logical vector `x > 0`, I can subset `x` on `x > 0` in two ways. I can use `which` or I can use the vector `x > 0` directly as the indexing. However, we must note that the two are not identical since `x[x > 0]` will preserve `NA`s while `x[which(x > 0)]` will not.

However, in either method, I will need to examine each element of the vector `x > 0`. In an explicit `which` call I will have to examine only the boolean state of the element while in a direct sub-setting operation I will have to examine both missing-ness and the boolean state of each element.

@flodel brings an interesting observation. Since `[`, `is.na`, `which`, and `|` are all primitives or internal routines, let's assume no extraordinary overhead and do this experiment:

```
microbenchmark(which(x > 0), x[which(x > 0)], x > 0 | is.na(x), x[x > 0],
               unit="us", times=1000)

Unit: microseconds
             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
     which(x > 0) 1219.274 1238.693 1261.439 1900.871 23085.57  1000
  x[which(x > 0)] 1554.857 1592.543 1974.370 2339.238 23816.99  1000
 x > 0 | is.na(x) 3439.191 3459.296 3770.260 4194.474 25234.70  1000
         x[x > 0] 3838.455 3876.816 4267.261 4621.544 25734.53  1000
```

Considering median values, we can see that, assuming `x > 0 | is.na(x)` is a crude model of what I am saying happens in logical sub-setting, then the actual time taken in 'subset' is ~ 500 us. And the time taken in 'subset' with which is ~ 700 us. Both the numbers are comparable and indicate that it is not the 'subset'ing itself which is costly in one method or another. In stead, it is what is being done to compute the subset wanted that is cheaper in the `which` method.

Comment: Yes, exactly, we are both speculating. I will try to update this when I can take time out to read the C code. But a very interesting observation indeed. I have personally always preferred to not use which in such situations. But I may switch after this.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be because subsetting by logical vector is slower than subsetting by numerical index.

```
> ii <- x > 4
> ij <- which(x > 4)
> 
> head(ii)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> head(ij)
[1] 3 4 6 7 8 9
>
> microbenchmark(x[ii], x[ij], times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min       lq    median        uq      max neval
 x[ii] 25.574977 26.15414 28.299858 31.080903 82.04686   100
 x[ij]  3.037134  3.31821  3.670096  7.516761 12.39738   100
```

---

Updated:

Probably one reason is that, smaller length of the index numeric can reduce the (internal) loop for subsetting and results in the slower evaluation. You can find `ik` < `ij` < `il`

But there would be another difference, because there is a huge difference between `ii` and `il`.

```
> ii <- x > 4
> 
> ij <- which(x > 4)
> ik <- which(x > 9)
> il <- which(x > -1)
> 
> microbenchmark(x[ii], x[ij], x[ik], x[il], times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
  expr       min         lq    median        uq       max neval
 x[ii] 25645.621 25986.2720 28466.412 30693.158 79582.484   100
 x[ij]  3111.974  3281.8280  3477.627  6142.216 55076.121   100
 x[ik]   585.723   628.2125   650.184   682.888  7551.084   100
 x[il]  5266.032  5773.9015  9073.614 10583.312 15113.791   100
```

Comment: Thanks Kohske. My question is basically *why* is this the case. I've made an edit to make this clearer.

Comment: Updated but probably you'd better dig into the source code (c implementation) of submitting if you really want to know where the overhead is.

Comment: You may want to update this post a bit, because your first sentence sounds kind of hilariously tautological in light of the question's new title.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it. Subsetting on a numeric allows pulling out exactly those elements that are required. Subsetting on a logical requires examining each element of the index vector to see if it's `TRUE`, and then building an internal list of the required elements of the target vector. There are two steps involved, so will take longer.

The difference is biggest is the number of elements extracted is small relative to the size of the original vector. For example:

```
> z <- rnorm(1e8)
> system.time(z[which(z < -5)])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.58    0.03    0.60 
> system.time(z[z < -5])
   user  system elapsed 
   2.56    0.14    2.70 
> system.time(z[which(z < 5)])
   user  system elapsed 
   1.39    0.30    1.68 
> system.time(z[z < 5])
   user  system elapsed 
   2.82    0.44    3.26
```

Here, if you're pulling out only a small proportion of elements (there were 23 elements of z < -5 in my test), using `which` takes a very small proportion compared to logical indexing. However, if you're extracting a large proportion of elements, the times are closer.

Comment: But isn't that being done by `which` as well, i.e. 'examining each element of the index vector'? Then the question becomes why is `which` faster than whatever method logical subsetting is using to 'building an internal list of the required elements of the target vector'.

Comment: @Arun: My point was on the fact that whether one does `which` or one does logical sub-setting, one is going to examine each element in the logical vector. Only, with `which` one is doing it explicitly while logical sub-setting deals with that implicitly. It must be the indifference to propagation of NAs that makes the first faster as that is the only additional work the latter is doing. Perhaps, we can come up with a way to measure this additional work?

Comment: @Arun: Your example, while well crafted, is tangential to my point. Perhaps, I am not being clear enough. `which` is greedy and only looks for TRUEs. Logical sub-setting, OTOH, needs to worry about missing-ness prior to checking the boolean state. In my mind, and I may be wrong, that is the extra work the latter is doing.

Comment: @Arun: I tried to 'Use the Source, Luke', but it went above my head! :\

Comment: @Arun, Speculation only, but I think `system.time(x[idx1])` and `system.time(x[which(idx1 | is.na(idx1))])` might be revealing. The two are pretty close in time. What is costly is the `|`.