# Remove the maximum value of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `v` and I want to remove the maximum value of the vector `v` from `v`. I can find that how many times each value repeated , but how can I remove maximum value of `v` from `v` in R?

```
v = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 5, 6, 6.5, 8, 8, 8)
max(v)
[1] 8
j = as.numeric(unname(table(v)))
j
[1] 2 3 1 1 1 3
```

Also, if I have another vector `a` which is

```
a = rep(1, length(v))
```

with same length as `v`, and I want to remove the last 3 ones , what should I do?

Comment: It is not appropriate to use a thread as a running place to ask questions.  Once a question has been answered please open a new thread to ask a new question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An alternative

```
v[v < max(v)]
[1] 0.25 0.25 0.30 0.30 0.30 5.00 6.00 6.50
```

Comment: Congratulations for the 10k.

Comment: Congrats and your approach is the fastest +1

Comment: @Tyler, are you sure about that? My intuition tells me that `<` should not be faster than `!=`. When I use `microbenchmark`, I don't think I am seeing any statistically significant difference...

Comment: @thelatemail: Thanks for youy reply. If I have another vector a = rep(1, length(v)) with same length as v , and I want to remove the last 3 ones , what should I do?

Comment: @rose - you shouldn't use the comments section to ask new questions - but `head(a,-3)` should do it.

Answer (score 9):

Likely logical indexing is faster here:

```
v[v != max(v)]

## > v[v != max(v)]
## [1] 0.25 0.25 0.30 0.30 0.30 5.00 6.00 6.50
```

**Edit**  Wanted to add the bench marks:

```
v <- rep(c(0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 5, 6, 6.5, 8, 8, 8), 10000) #repeat 10,000 x

a <-function() v[v != max(v)]
b <-function() v[-which(v == max(v))]
d <- function() v[!v== max(v)]
e <- function() v[v < max(v)]
f <- function() v[which(v != max(v))]
g <- function() v[which(v < max(v))]
```

On 100 replications with the microbenchmark package (win 7 machine):

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
##   a() 2.854048 2.990731 3.200889 4.734276 54.814676   100
##   b() 3.268299 3.487321 3.642666 5.241360  6.254832   100
##   d() 3.016389 3.265034 3.454200 5.027703 54.879986   100
##   e() 2.748151 2.892300 3.095694 4.475367  5.394139   100
##   f() 2.047936 2.208645 2.423001 3.967349 54.291730   100
##   g() 1.948105 2.208178 2.352093 3.860988  4.995748   100
```

**EDIT (arun)**

Logical indexing a vector, as far as I've seen, is slower than using "which" and indexing on the elements directly. That is what makes the difference. I also created a post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510778/why-is-subsetting-on-a-logical-type-slower-than-subetting-on-numeric-type) to understand why, and I'd like an answer if someone has one... :)

Comment: Yours was slightly different and I benched it and it came in only slightly behind mine.

Comment: Nice comparisons - I wouldn't have expected such an obvious difference between a() and e()

Comment: @alexwhan - It should be noted that it's only fractions of seconds different when processing upwards of a million cases. While a bit of fun, it's probably not overly concerning.

Comment: I'm not concerned! Just interested that there's any difference between `<` and `!=`

Comment: Thanks. If I have another vector a = rep(1, length(v)) with same length as v , and I want to remove the last 3 ones , what should I do?

Comment: @TylerRinker, try benchmarking with this. It'll be faster. `v[which(v != max(v))]` and `v[which(v < max(v))]`. If you don't mind, I can add in the results.

Answer (score 2):

```
v[-which(v == max(v))]
# [1] 0.25 0.25 0.30 0.30 0.30 5.00 6.00 6.50
```

`which(v == max(v))` returns the positions of `v` that are equal to the maximum value:

```
which(v == max(v))
[1]  9 10 11
```

So we're just saying remove values that are in these positions.

Comment: even shorter `v[-which.max(v)]`

Comment: @haki that only seems to remove the last 8, not all three 8's.

Comment: @Mark Miller to nitpick,  I think it removes the first 8 not the last one as ``?which.max`` indicates that it gives the index of the first maximum.