# How to find the smallest values of the vectors sequentially

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `x` and I would like to find the smallest values of this vector. Then, I would like to return a new `x` without the selected element and then extract the smallest value from the remaining values and so on.

For example,

```
x <- c(3,4,2,1,6,10.14,100,7)
```

I would like to extract the smallest value of this vector. In this example, the smallest value is 1. Then, I would like to return `x` without `1`.

```
x_1 <- c(3,4,2,6,10.14,100,7)
```

After that, I need to select the smallest value from `x_1` and then get `x_2` and so on.

How can I do this automatically in R?

Comment: Start with `x[-which.min(x)]`.

Comment: Related: [Remove the maximum value of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937992/remove-the-maximum-value-of-a-vector-in-r). Now you just need to iterate (eg., with `while`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a function `remove_small_vec` which removes the lowest value from the vector. We then run a `while` loop which runs till `length` of vector is `>=` 1.

```
remove_small_vec <- function(vec) {
   vec[vec != min(vec)]
}

list_vec <- list()

while (length(x) >= 1) {
   list_vec <- c(list_vec, list(x))
   x <- remove_small_vec(x)
}


list_vec
#[[1]]
#[1]   3.00   4.00   2.00   1.00   6.00  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[2]]
#[1]   3.00   4.00   2.00   6.00  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[3]]
#[1]   3.00   4.00   6.00  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[4]]
#[1]   4.00   6.00  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[5]]
#[1]   6.00  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[6]]
#[1]  10.14 100.00   7.00

#[[7]]
#[1]  10.14 100.00

#[[8]]
#[1] 100
```

This returns a list of vectors of `length` same as `x` with one element removed in each list element.

**data**

```
x <- c(3,4,2,1,6,10.14,100,7)
```