# Index / Select all of the non-missing / NA columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a lot of NAs.  When doing exploratory analysis I would prefer to look at just the non-missing columns when I print to the screen.

```
mtcars[ 1 , 1 ] <- NA
mtcars[ 2 , 2 ] <- NA
```

I am looking for an efficent way to select all the non-missing columns for a paticular row.  For example in this modifed version of mtcars I would like to select columns 2:11 when looking at row one.  For row two select c(1, 3:11).  I suspect there is an apply statement I can use here but have managed to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
viewRow <- function(x,row) x[row,!is.na(x[row,])]
viewRow(mtcars,1)
          cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
viewRow(mtcars,2)
              mpg disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4 Wag  21  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me code that worked

```
names(mtcars)[ which(!is.na(mtcars[ 1 ,   ] )) ]
names(mtcars)[ which(!is.na(mtcars[ 2 ,   ] )) ]
```

might be a better way - but this works

Comment: You can write that without the `which` in there.

Comment: @beginneR, although I seem to remember reading somewhere that `which` makes the statement faster...

Comment: @beginneR, found what I was thinking of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17510778/1270695