# Simple way to prevent data.table auto-index from being created without using options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)

Tags: r, data.table

I have some code like

```
library(data.table)  # v 1.12.3

foo <- data.table(x = sample(letters, 10^6, replace = T), y = 1)
foo[x == "a", y := 0]
indices(foo)  # x
```

As you can see, an index is being created automatically on the column `x`. In this case, I don't want the index to be created. I know I can prevent it with something like

```
options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
foo[x == "a", y := 0]
options(datatable.auto.index = TRUE)
```

but this seems like poor design because

1. It's messy code
2. If `foo[x == "a", y := 0]` has an error, auto-indexes will not get turned back on

Is there a better option here, perhaps something like `foo[x == "a", y := 0, autoindex = FALSE]`?

Also, I guess I could allow the index to be created and then just delete it with `setindex(foo, NULL)` but I'm concerned this has an added performance cost. Plus it seems messier than it should be.

Comment: Wrap in parentheses?

Comment: An additional option is using `foo[which(x == "a"), y := 0]`. This seems faster on my working laptop, likely `data.table` is optimized for single numeric arguments, avoiding any overhead with checking argument for logical structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For cases like your example, I think it's better to let data.table do its thing:

```
library(data.table)  # v 1.12.3 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2019-07-29 22:08:45 UTC
foo <- data.table(x = sample(letters, 10^8, replace = T), y = 1)

# allow optimization (forder, store order as index, bmerge value)
foo1 = copy(foo)
system.time({
  foo1[x == "a", y := 0]
})
stopifnot(length(indices(foo1)) > 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.43    0.39    0.56 

# disable optimization, hacky
foo2 = copy(foo)
system.time({
  foo2[(x == "a"), y := 0]
})
stopifnot(length(indices(foo2)) == 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.47    0.01    0.49 

# disable optimization, properly
foo2 = copy(foo)
system.time({
  options(datatable.auto.index = FALSE)
  foo[x == "a", y := 0]
  options(datatable.auto.index = TRUE)
})
stopifnot(length(indices(foo2)) == 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.48    0.00    0.49 

# disable optimization, from @Oliver in comments
foo2 = copy(foo)
system.time({
  foo2[which(x == "a"), y := 0]
})
stopifnot(length(indices(foo2)) == 0)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.54    0.03    0.50
```

Misc comments:

- The parentheses `(x == "a")` prevent the data.table parser from recognizing that optimized subsetting is appropriate. For details on the optimizations used, turn on the `verbose=TRUE` argument.
- I regard the additional cost above as small, and the benefits in subsequent queries as large:

  ```
  system.time({
    foo1[x == "b", y := 0]
  })
  #    user  system elapsed 
  #    0.17    0.12    0.25
  ```
- Maybe for other auto-indexed queries, the time difference would be larger than in this case.
- Besides time to compute, indices presumably take up some space (storing a permutation of the table's row numbers?), but I doubt that would be worth fiddling with in most cases.

Comment: another option is using `foo[which(x == "b"), y := 0]`. For single calls this seems faster than using `(x == "b")`, upon testing with my laptop. Might be worth adding to the brilliant answer for comparison.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks :) added. My timings put it on par with the others, fwiw. I remember hearing that which() was faster, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510778/why-is-subsetting-on-a-logical-type-slower-than-subsetting-on-numeric-type/17510814 though I thought R made some change to fix that at some point.

Comment: Hm, looking at the R changelog, I only see a note about improvement in a special case of `x[x != 0]` "Thanks to a patch from Tomas Kalibera, x[x != 0] is now typically faster than x[which(x != 0)] (in the case where x has no NAs, the two are equivalent)."

Comment: It should not be equivalent because `which(x!=0)` has to allocate `logical(length(x))`, then allocate `integer(sum(x!=0))`. While `x!=0` will allocate only `logical(length(x))`. The bigger T/F ratio is the closer we are getting to twice more memory requirement of the `which` way. Related https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3663

Answer (score 5):

`datatable.auto.index` option was my idea just because there was no official way to disable automatic creation of index. It was useful specially when benchmarking. I still think it is better to use option than adding new argument to `[.data.table`.

It is not clear why exactly you don't want to use auto index. If you are worried about potential overhead then simple check could examine if it is really a problem.
My suggestion then, is to disable `auto.index` for good just after loading data.table. Then for each data.table you want to use any index call `setindex`.